# Get-AzureStorageBlob Catch exception / error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I have a script downloading multiple blobs from Azure using the following command

```
 try { 
    Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $backupName -Context $context -Container $containerName -Destination $DownloadPath -Force 
}
catch {
     Write-LogError "Error downloading backup - $backupName"
}
```

It runs in a loop and downloads some backups correctly. However, some files are of size 0kb.
When I retry downloading the same file, it downloads correctly.
Is there a way to catch any error while downloading file and retry if it did not download correctly the first time?
Edit - Also no exception / error caught.

Comment: I had same problem with `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy` cmdlet. It occasionally creates 0kb file on destination and don't throw any error.  I don't remember what exactly situation they were but my copy targets was vhd files and they could be in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell cmdlets will generally not throw terminating errors, you need to use "-ErrorAction Stop" if you want to do that (only terminating errors get caught by try/catch). As for the 0kb problem, should be easy enough to test the size of the downloaded file and make a decision about re-downloading.